# Symfony2 doctrine cascade delete child relation

Tags: symfony, doctrine

Consider a Parent with 0..n Child's. When I remove a Child from the Parent, and persist the Parent object, I need the Child to be removed. Currently, the only way I got that working is to actually remove the Child as well, like such:

```
$parent->removeChild($child);
$em->remove($child);
```

I think my relations are setup correctly, since if I remove the Parent entirely the Child's are being removed from the db too. Why isn't the following line sufficient for removing the Child?:

```
$parent->removeChild($child);
```

Little background info: I am trying to update a Parent object with x Child objects, I need previously associated Child's to be removed and new Child's to be added. But I feel I should need to iterate over both collections to find out which ones to remove and/or add.

Does anybody have a clear example of this? And please forget about Symfony's/Doctrine's documentation,. I've read it all!

Comment: According to the docs, you have to do both, but they recommend to encapsulate this into a function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Children have their own lives, and you shouldn't get rid of them just because they separate from their parents. Put a different way, these are separate entities, and there are many use cases where you would break a relation but still want to maintain both objects, so we do not automatically remove an object when we remove its relation.

Your instinct was right, you do need to iterate over both lists. I know you said you read all the documentation, but take a second look at the end of [How to Embed a Collection of Forms](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/form_collections.html#allowing-tags-to-be-removed). It includes a working edit function for the parent object which does exactly that.

Comment: Your explanation sounds fair. The iterations i mentioned are exactly like the documentation you point out. However, i got a controller for the web and an REST api controller to edit my Parent object Child's. If you look at the documentation, this means i got 4 "foreach" statements just to take care of the child relations. Having two seperate controllers means that i actually need 8 statements just to update the childs. I felt this could be done in an cleaner, easier way?

Comment: In terms of not iterating, php doesn't really have the sort of data structures (like a python dict) that you would need to handle this more directly. You could probably engineer something more efficient, but unless you are dealing with large arrays this shouldn't become a big problem. As to code efficiency, you are right, the is unnecessarily repetitive. As @jaudette suggested, I would encapsulate the whole process in a function, probably in the doctrine class for the entity. then you could simply call $object->editChildren($array) and keep all the logic in one place.

Answer (score 1):

If you have child entities which should not exist without the parent and the parent privately ownes the children then you can use orphanRemoval.

```
/** 
 * @OneToOne(targetEntity="StandingData", orphanRemoval=true) 
 */
private $standingData;

$contact->standingData(new StandingData("Firstname", "Lastname", "Street"));
```

If the contact had an old "standingData" it will be deleted from the DB.
See http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/working-with-associations.html#orphan-removal for more info.